# SQL Query 3rd term date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

```
INSERT INTO `empleado` VALUES ('100', 'Alfonso', '1999-11-22', '100', '11');
INSERT INTO `empleado` VALUES ('101', 'Encarna', '2001-11-12', '100', '15');
INSERT INTO `empleado` VALUES ('102', 'Paco', '1999-10-16', '101', '12');
INSERT INTO `empleado` VALUES ('103', 'Juan Carlos', '1999-01-12', '101', '10');
```

That's my Date Type ,I need to select some codes that got into the company in the 3rd term of 1999

```
"select nombre,coddep,fecha_ingreso from 
empleado where fecha_ingreso >1999;"
```

-that was my initial query, but it's wrong since it selects the `name`,`cod` and `datetime >1999`

Comment: Do you mean 3rd quarter of 1999, with Jan-Mar being the 1st quarter?

Comment: yes, jan-april would be the first term

Comment: Jan-April? That's 4 months, a quarter is only 3 months.

Comment: Whatever months you want, put them into my answer.

Comment: yes, I needed last 4 months , (terms of 4 months),already got it,thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fetch rows in the 3rd calendar quarter of 1999:

```
SELECT nombre, coddep, fecha_ingreso
FROM empleado
WHERE fecha_ingreso BETWEEN '1999-07-01' AND '1999-09-30'
```

If the field is DATETIME rather than DATE, change the second date to `1999-09-30 12:59:59`

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! i just made some changes in the date since i needed 3rd term    "SELECT nombre, coddep, fecha_ingreso
FROM empleado
WHERE fecha_ingreso BETWEEN '1999-08-01' AND '1999-12-30'"

Comment: I prefer this answer to using `YEAR(Date)` and `QUARTER(Date)` as it can take advantage of an index on the date column, but this only works for a `DATE` column and not a `DATETIME`, something with a date of `1999-09-30 15:00` for example would be omitted. I'd be inclined to use ` > '1999-07-01' AND Fecha_ingreso < '1999-10-01'`. Aaron Bertrand has discussed his dislike of using BETWEEN with Dates [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), and I'm inclined to agree with him.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT nombre, coddep, fecha_ingreso
  FROM empleado
  WHERE YEAR(fecha_ingreso) = 1999 AND QUARTER(fecha_ingreso) = 3
;
```